# performance and security on PHP routing

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess, security, routes

this is my first routing system on PHP. as you can see it's very simple.
any advice or tip about it that can make it better? i wanna make it better so i could use it in real websites.
first i include db connect, then get the URL, if the URL have special index like post id or post name, then include post.php or if $sp_link[4] == profile then load the profile.php. 
PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    require_once 'inc/header.php';
    include_once 'inc/nav.php';


    $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    // echo $actual_link;
    $sp_link = explode("/", $actual_link);
    print_r($sp_link);


    $sql ='SELECT * from posts WHERE post_id=? AND post_name=?';
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([@$sp_link[5], @$sp_link[6]]);
    $post=$stmt->fetch();

    if ($sp_link[4] == 'blog' && @$sp_link[5] == '' ) {
        // @include 'blog.php';
        //$page_title = $post->post_title;
    }
    else if ($sp_link[4] == 'profile' && @$sp_link[5] == '' ) {
        @include_once 'profile.php';
    }
    else if ($sp_link[4] == 'login' && @$sp_link[5] == '' ) {
        @include 'login.php';
        $page_title = 'ورود';
    }
    else if ($sp_link[4] == 'signup' && @$sp_link[5] == '' ) {
        @include 'signup.php';
        $page_title = 'ورود';
    }
    else if ($sp_link[4] == 'blog' && @$sp_link[5] == $post->post_id && @$sp_link[6] ==     $post->post_name) {
        @include 'post.php';
        $page_title = $post->post_title;

    }
    else if (($sp_link[4] == '' || $sp_link[4] == 'index' || $sp_link[4] == 'index.php') &&     @$sp_link[5] == '') {
           $page_title = 'سکان آکادمی | آموزش برنامه نویسی';
            include 'home.php';
    }
    else if (($sp_link[4] == 'blog' && $sp_link[5] == '12342') && @$sp_link[6] == '') {
        include_once 'post.php';
    } else {
        include_once '404.php';
    }
```

and this is htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Comment: If this code is working and you're looking for opinions on it, you should consider moving it to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: it's working but the structure is so simple that i ashamed to show it to anybody!